# Why use the "gradient" in gradient boosting?

Tags: machine-learning, boosting, gradient-descent

Let us say we want to predict a one dimensional, real valued $Y$ from $X$. In gradient boosting, the final model $f$ is built by adding the prediction of several trees, essentially $f_1 + \dots + f_M$. Each tree $f_m$ is built using the following recursion: $$f_m(x) = f_{m-1} + \nu \cdot t(x),$$ where $t$ is a new tree and $\nu$ is the learning rate.

Now, it makes sense to fit $t$ to the residuals, since we want to predict$y$ as $\tilde{y} = f_{m-1}(x) + f_{m}(x)$, and then $f_{m}(x) = y - f_{m-1}(x)$. This means, in principle, that the new tree being built should predict $y-f_{m-1}(x)$ for each $(x,y)$ pairs in the dataset. The learning rate reduces the influence of each newly added tree, yielding a more robust method.

As far as I know, this is the standard boosting method. However, I am finding trouble understanding why using the *gradient* is helpful. Why would we want to fit the tree on the gradient of the loss function?